# Applet is not loaded properly in browser.need to refresh the browser

Tags: java, applet

I have made jar file based applet.

I have used Quick time for java API.

Applet is hosted in Cisco camera.

When I open camera URL java applet sometimes not loaded. So I need to refresh the browser.

Kindly suggest some solution.

This problem does not happen frequently.Sometime it works perfectly.

Sometimes I need to refresh the browser manually.

Comment: You should configure your Java applet logs (for windows it is in control panel -> Java) and analyze what happens on web page load.

Comment: Applet is not loaded.So how should i see the logs?